# Matlab: From 'edit' (textbox input) to mathematical expression

Tags: matlab

I have a `uicontrol` of type 'edit' and I want to be able to write something like `sin(2*10*pi*t)-sin(2*15*pi*t)` on it and then this string to become an expression for a variable F, for example: `F=sin(2*10*pi*t)-sin(2*15*pi*t);` where `t` is previously declared.

```
string=get(uicontrol_data, 'String');
%now I have the string value of the input
```

What should I do in order to transform the string into an expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the built-in [`eval`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function. For instance:

```
string = get(uicontrol_data, 'String');
eval(['F = ' string ';']);   % Equivalent of F = ...;
```

Best,

Comment: It is not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... If I use `eval(['x = ' 2 ';'])` I get the error: `Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.` and if I use  `eval(['x = ' Fc ';'])` where Fc is given i get: `Error: Expression or statement is incomplete or incorrect.`

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `eval` (which is generally [not recommended](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html)) by means of [`str2func`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
str = get(uicontrol_data, 'String'); %// reads string grom uicontrol
f = str2func(['@(t)' str]);  %// creates anonymous function and function handle
F = f(t); %// evaluates that function for the previously declared variable `t`
```